# Peek is not working in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

We have created one sample custom class "Customer".

```
public class Customer
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string Addresss { get; set; }
}
```

That we stored in TempData.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{  
  Customer customer = new Customer()
  {
    FirstName = "FirstName",
    LastName = "LastName",
    Addresss = "Address"
   };

   TempData["Customer"] = customer;
   return RedirectToAction("About");
 }
```

That redirect to another action method and render the view of "About".

```
 public ActionResult About()
 {
   Customer customer = new Customer();
   if (TempData["Customer"] != null)
   {
    customer = TempData.Peek("Customer") as Customer;
   }    
   return View();
  }
```

In view, one link button is there "Contact". When we click on this button that will come into the action method "Contact".

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
 Customer customer = new Customer();
 if (TempData["Customer"] != null)
 {
  customer = TempData["Customer"] as Customer;
 }   
 return View();
}
```

But in this case TempData["Customer"] is null. Why TempData["Customer"] is not persist data when we are using peek?

Comment: well, it is called `TempData` for a reason I guess. if you want it to persist, you can either save it in `application data` or `session data` (if that works for you).
but what I don't understand is what is your design? why does the about page data initializes inside the index? and why do you pass the parameters using `TempData`, when you can pass them in your `redirectToAction` method.

Comment: I am new in MVC. Actually I want to check TempData sould persist on two requests when we are using "Peek". The same scenario is working in "Keep". But it's not working in "Peek".

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to do double TeamData reading.

I guess it will be correct way to Peek without pre reading/checking a value.

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
   Customer customer = TempData.Peek("Customer") as Customer;
   if (customer == null)
   {
      customer = new Customer();
   }   
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the "Customer" value in the if statement condition. So the value is destroyed once it is read. As a result, it will return null in the second read, TempData.Peek("Customer").

```
Customer customer  = (Customer)TempData["Customer"];
if (customer != null)
{
    //Do your work.
}
```

Comment: Actually good question, I also got caught by this trap. For primitive types TempData, like int, Convert.ToInt32 will help to avoid null check.

Answer (score 0):

TempData keeps the information for the time of an HTTP Request. This mean only from one page to another
Since when you click on contact action link you are redirecting second time and life of tempdata dictionary is over
Ref: [TempData](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/What-is-ViewData-ViewBag-and-TempData-MVC-Option)